# Server.MapPath - Could not find a part of the path in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, directory, runtime-error

I am uploading a file to my server using Server.MapPath

When I run my code I get the following error

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\SitePages\uploads\ABI
>   Employee List.xlsx'.

So Yes, I dont have that directory on my server. I only have a directory up to here.

> 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\

So, I go and create Those directories.

The weird thing is, is that if I create a folder with the name "SitePages" in the above directory, my site doesn't even want to start up? Delete it and it works again. (Image of error below)

I need to create that directory to upload the file to my server, but I can't, since everything breaks. How will i fix this? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a directory in root  eg. **'Foldername'** and try the following

```
  DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Foldername/"));
            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                dir.Create();
            }
            // this makes sure that directory has been created
            // do other stuff
```

Comment: worked, thanks.
(I only have SErver.MapPath, not HttpContent.Server.MapPath)

Answer (score 1):

You have create one folder name manually in virtual directory and try this code:

```
    public static string GetPath()
    {
        string Path = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/FolderName/");
        }
        catch (Exception _e)
        {
        }
        return Path;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create the desired folder at runtime.
you can create a directory by

```
if(!Directory.Exists("YourDirectory"))
{
Directory.CreateDirectory("YourDirectory")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a directory in root eg. 'Images' and try the following

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\Images\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));
}
```