# Could not find a part of the path: Server.mapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I'm trying to save a banner picture and before saving to a folder I'm checking and creating the respective folder as well but it gives me error even though I checked that the folder exists. Here is the code:

```
HttpPostedFileBase banner = Request.Files["banner"];
if (banner != null && banner.ContentLength > 0) {
    var folder = Server.MapPath("~/images/Continents/");
    if (!Directory.Exists(folder)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
    }
    banner.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/Continents/" + image.FileName));
    string x = "/images/Continents/" + image.FileName;
    continent.BANNER = x;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: In which line are you getting the error ? `SaveAs` ?

Comment: and what is `image` object of ? where is it coming from ?

Comment: I think this is slightly a duplicate of this question [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357839/server-mappath-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-in-asp-net)

Comment: add `error` statement as well.

Comment: @Shyju yes! Image object is coming from the view to controlled via PostRequest.

Comment: @Ramki No, I've encountered to this problem for first time.

Comment: @mmushtaq No bro, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @JackXandar i haven't said it is duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate Paths in `Server.MapPath`, use `Path.Combine()` as follow:

```
banner.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/images/Continents", image.FileName)));
```

Comment: I have used this code: '                banner.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/images/Continents/" + image.FileName)));
'

Comment: Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\users\amir\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\SevenZones\SevenZones\images\Continents' is denied.

Comment: Use `Path.Combin("~/images/Continents" , image.FileName)`. dont use `+` .

Comment: This `exception` show that you have to add `permission` for your `project directory`.